# SQLite conditional output

Tags: sql, sqlite, spiceworks

I need to output a X in a column in a report created using ONLY SQLite.

I need it to find a patern, and if that pattern exsists for that record output a X, if its not found output a blank space.

Heres what I have.

```
SELECT `device_type` AS "Device",
SUBSTR(`model`, 1, 30) AS "Model",
  `location` AS "Location",
  (CASE WHEN (`user_tag` LIKE "%decommissioned%" THEN "X" ELSE " " END) AS "Decom",
  count(`id`) AS "Count"
FROM `devices`
GROUP BY `device_type` ORDER BY `device` ASC;
```

Its reporting

```
near "THEN": syntax error
```

Like I said, I can ONLY use SQL for putting the report together.  Its a little limiting but its all im allowed to use for this.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: try to remove the `(` bracket right before `user_tag`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the right syntax:

```
SELECT `device_type` AS Device,
       SUBSTR(`model`, 1, 30) AS Model,
       `location` AS "Location",
        (CASE WHEN `user_tag` LIKE "%decommissioned%" THEN "X" ELSE " " END) AS "Decom",
        count(`id`) AS "Count"
FROM `devices`
GROUP BY device_type, SUBSTR(`model`, 1, 30), location,
         (CASE WHEN `user_tag` LIKE "%decommissioned%" THEN "X" ELSE " " END)
ORDER BY `device` ASC;
```

You have an extra opening paren.  But in addition, the `group by` clause does not match the `select` in terms of the columns being used to define groups.